# browser.windows.each doesn't work watir webdriver

Tags: browser, watir-webdriver

I don't understand why this code doesn't work (ruby 1.9.3 484):

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'watir-webdriver'


browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome  #open chrome
browser.window.resize_to(1280, 960)
browser.goto "http://stackoverflow.com/"


browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome  #new window chrome
browser.window.resize_to(1280, 960)
browser.goto "http://google.fr/"

browser.windows.each{|wb|puts wb.url}
```

The result:

http://google.fr/

Comment: You don't open new window by "Watir::Browser.new :chrome", you just start new browser instance. This is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

ok thx a lot man of snow!!! is it right?

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'watir-webdriver'


browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome  #open chrome
browser.window.resize_to(1280, 960)
browser.goto "http://stackoverflow.com/"


browser.execute_script("window.open('http://yahoo.com')")

browser.windows.each{|wb|puts wb.url}
```

Comment: Why are you using #execute_script instead of just another #goto?

What exactly are you trying to do? These sample scripts seem very contrived.